# How to set the breaks for the annotation row function of the package pheatmap in R

Tags: r, pheatmap

I'm using pheatmap and I don't know how to set the breakpoints for a data frame that specifies the annotations shown on the left side of the heatmap. I know that using the breaks function you can determine the breaks of the data being plotted, but how to do the same with the annotations you add to the plot? Here I put the code-example:

```
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ALL)
library(gplots)

data("ALL")
expressionData = exprs(ALL)

#setting breaks to 0 to 5 then 5.01 to 10
breaks = c(seq(0, 5, length.out = 101),seq(5.01, 10, length.out = 101))
breaks2 <- breaks

#setting colors
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(n = 201)

#generation of the data from the gene that we want to put on the left side of our pheatmap
data_gene <- as.data.frame(expressionData[1:10,1])
colnames(data_gene) <- "gene"

#setting the annotation row and setting the color of data_gene
annotation_row = data.frame(data_gene)
ann_colors = list(gene= bluered(75))

#pheatmap
pheatmap(expressionData[1:10, ], color = my_palette, breaks = breaks2, annotation_row = annotation_row, annotation_colors = ann_colors)
```

[pheatmap result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFSdU.png)

Here, the breaks for "gene" are set automatically and go from 4 to 9. Let's say I want them to go from 0 to 5 and then to 5.01 to 10. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain better what you mean for "I know that using the breaks function you can determine the breaks of the data being plotted, but how to do the same with the annotations you add to the plot?" and detail the expected output. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain properly.With the function breaks,I set the breaks for the data in expressionData (which is the data that we are seeing in the heatmap). Now, I also added an annotation_row which add information about a specific gene (data_gene). If you see now the legend of the heatmap you will see that the breaks for the expressionData go from 0 to 10 as we set it with the breaks function. However, the legend for the annotation_row we added (gene) is set automatically depending on its values (from 4 to 9 here). How I can change the values of the legend gene to go as well from 0 to 10?